# Why am I unable to associate parameter to the fields of sub data set?

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a query in the main data set. And then another query in the subdata set.

I have a table element made out of subdata set. Now for the query in the sub data set I want to pass a filter condition in the where clause.

The parameter that I would create should be usable in the subdataset.

As of now when I create a parameter, I am unable to use it as a where clause in the subdata set.  In the parameter map, it only shows the main data fields. How do I associate the parameter to the fields in the sub data set?

Answer (score 1):

You need to:

**Add the parameter in the subdatset**

[image: Add sub dataset param]

```
<subDataset name="subdataset">
    <parameter name="mySubParam" class="java.lang.String"/>
    .....
</subDataset>
```

Then **pass the parameter** when you use this subdataset

[image]

```
<datasetRun subDataset="subdataset" uuid="1af74bfd-3a01-4696-9290-ae1d9f1e5d5a">
    <datasetParameter name="mySubParam">
       <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{myParam}]]></datasetParameterExpression>
    </datasetParameter>
    ...         
</datasetRun>
```